ISession instabilities
I am trying to use ISession in a .net Blazor web app server side only. My problem is that the ISession in very unstable as it disappear and comeback when it feels like it.
First in the program.cs i added the session like so :
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Set timeout
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

And right after the build :
var app = builder.Build();

I added the session to it
app.UseSession();

Now here the default home page that comes in an empty project and i added a button to demonstrate with console write to see what is happening :
@page "/"
@page "/Home"
@inject IHttpContextAccessor hca

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button @onclick="Click">click</button>

@code{   
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"Home.Initialized - SessionId = {hca.HttpContext.Session.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($@"Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = {hca.HttpContext.Session.Keys.ToList().Count}");
     
        hca.HttpContext.Session.SetString("test", "tesatassad");
    }

    private void Click()
    {
        hca.HttpContext.Session.SetString("test1", "tesatassad");
        hca.HttpContext.Session.SetString("test2", "tesatassad");

        Console.WriteLine($@"Home.Click - SessionId = {hca.HttpContext.Session.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($@"Home.Click - Keys.Count = {hca.HttpContext.Session.Keys.ToList().Count}");    
    }    
}

The whole idea is to log the session id and the amount of keys in it on initialized and when i click the button. Now just running the page i have the first issue. The pages always trigger OnInitialized twice.
I made the log purposely before the new key is created to see it so the log shows that the second trigger is valid (which make sense)
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 0
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 1

Now lets click the button. The button set 2 new key and display the count after and check the full log again
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 0
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 1
Home.Click - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Click - Keys.Count = 3

Now this make sense, i have my double load and i have the log after the set in the button showing addition of 2 keys for a total of 3.
Now let's refresh the page with F5 and check the log :
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 0
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 1
Home.Click - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Click - Keys.Count = 3
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 1
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 3

Again you see the double log but the first is wrong. It lost all the key but the session id is still the same. What is this coming from ? how can you tell when to try to read session only on the second OnInitialized ?
Now this is even weirder, Let's click F5 again to refresh the page once more
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 0
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 1
Home.Click - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Click - Keys.Count = 3
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 1
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 3
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 3
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 846bc865-7b0f-de46-c4d0-f015eb1b4389
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 3

Now the second F5 the session keys exist in both call of OnInitialized. From now on it will work for any navigation combination you want and the session is always up to date.
My major problem is that i need to load data in the page in the OnInitialized but it need to use values stored server side in the ISession. Being so unstable there must be something i am missing

What Rendermode is the page using.  Is Interactivity set to global or per page/component.  Note that the HttpContext is only available in statically rendered/pre-rendered pages.  And you should access it by the cascaded HttpContext.  It will be null in an interactive page/component.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I am set to Global

This is where using the IHttpContextAccessor gets you into trouble.  The context it supplies is stale.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor
The recommended practice is to use the new built in cascaded HttpContext.
Here's your page using the cascade.
@page "/"
@page "/Home"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button @onclick="Click">click</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private HttpContext? httpContext { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"Home.Initialized - SessionId = {httpContext?.Session.Id ?? "Null"}");
        Console.WriteLine($@"Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = {httpContext?.Session.Keys.ToList().Count.ToString() ??  "Null"}");
        Console.WriteLine($@"Home.Initialized - Cascaded SessionId = {httpContext?.Session.Id ?? "Null"}");

        httpContext?.Session.SetString("test", "tesatassad");
    }

    private void Click()
    {}
}

Which will log the following:
Home.Initialized - SessionId = 2a33a7b3-d9db-1552-373a-f7ee35f2d156
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = 0
Home.Initialized - Cascaded SessionId = 2a33a7b3-d9db-1552-373a-f7ee35f2d156
Home.Initialized - SessionId = Null
Home.Initialized - Keys.Count = Null
Home.Initialized - Cascaded SessionId = Null

Note that the HttpContext for the interactive session is null, which explains your instability.
You'll need to explain your use case better for an answer to how do I do what I want to.

I see the same results as you. So i guess that mean there is really no way to store temporarily information related to 1 user session on the server side. Everything has to be persistent using a third party like database or some caching solution.

You can persist state from pre-render to interactive using PersistentComponentState 

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state

